# How to read partial file name in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a file named "test PID 1100 DELAY **322ms**.aac" which i am getting using the following code :-

```
for %%i in (test*.aac) do SET "AACFILE=%%~ni"
D:\Converter\bin\faad.exe -o C:\fb\%1.wav "C:\fb\%AACFILE%.aac"
```

After this i need to read the numeric value between **DELAY and .aac** from the file and echo it in the following line at the end.

```
D:\Converter\bin\EAC3to.exe C:\fb\%1.wav C:\fb\%1-Synced.wav +322ms
```

Also i need to add 100 to the echoed value, For example if the value in file is 322ms then i want to output 422ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=5 delims=. " %%a in (%AACFILE%) do (
  set num=%%a & set num=!num:ms=! & set /a num=!num!+100
  D:\Converter\bin\EAC3to.exe C:\fb\%1.wav C:\fb\%1-Synced.wav +!num!ms
)
```

Comment: That works, now how do i add these lines at the end of existing line to replace the +322ms ?

    D:\Converter\bin\EAC3to.exe C:\fb\%1.wav C:\fb\%1-Synced.wav +322ms

Comment: Can you please help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937047/clean-batch-script-code